# Problema Base de datos Login com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: null

Estoy haciendo un Login con una base de datos MySQL localhost/127.0.0.1 tengo dos consultas, el usuario y la contraseña, la salida tiene que ser que un botón(**Login Frame**) lea los dos y lo mande al menú. EL código del botón(**Login Frame**) y el de la conexión hacen que tiren un error.

Error:

```
jul 13, 2020 7:34:42 PM Frames.Login btnIngresarActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM login WHERE user_name = 'Sebastian' AND user_pass = '1234'' at line 1
```

Este es el código:

```
       try{
        Conectar Con = new Conectar();
       String u = txtUsuario.getText();
       String c = txtPassword.getText();
       Con.ConectarBasedeDatos();
       String SQL = "SELECT FROM login WHERE user_name = '"+u+"' AND user_pass = '"+c+"' ";
       Con.resultado = Con.sentencia.executeQuery(SQL);
            while(Con.resultado.next()){
                if(Con.resultado.getString("i").equals("i")){
                    setVisible(false);
                    Menu men = new Menu();
                    setVisible(true);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario o Contraseña Invalida...");
            }
            }
            Con.DesconectarBasedeDatos();
       }catch(SQLException ex){
       Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
```

Si me podrian ayudar con este problema se los agradeceria bastante.. Gracias por ver mi problema :>

Comment: Te falta indicar en el `SELECT` la(s) columna(s) que quieres traer.

Comment: No me queda claro que intentas hacer al poner: if(Con.resultado.getString("i").equals("i")){

Comment: Busca el resultado por el correo, y luego validas la contraseña, no en la misma búsqueda, porque no vas a saber si el usuario existe, o si la contraseña es incorrecta. Aparte, user_name es una llave primaria potencialmente, hará la consulta muy rápido.

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en el Select. No has indicado que campos quieres retornar.

Podrías tal vez cambiar:

```
String SQL = "SELECT FROM login WHERE user_name = '"+u+"' AND user_pass = '"+c+"' ";
```

Por

```
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = '"+u+"' AND user_pass = '"+c+"' ";
```

Eso debería quitarte el error que te sale aunque muy posiblemente se te presenten otros.

Comment: En el tutorial me presentaba que iba COUNT (id) ahí, el campo id es el que quiero retornar, pero me manda error que el comando "COUNT" no existe, entonces no se que ira ahí..

Comment: Esto que comentas debes agregarlo a tu pregunta. No se de que tutorial me hablas por que tampoco lo mencionaste. Ese COUNT al que te refieres tampoco aparece en nada del texto que colocaste. Si tienes que agregar un count y no sabes por que te marca error debes consultar también un manual de SQL para orientarte en lo que estas haciendo. Si una consulta falla cuando la invocas con Java prueba ejecutandola desde el motor de base de datos. Si marca error es que esta mal hecha la consulta, si ahí no falla entonces se esta invocando mal desde Java.

Comment: https://byspel.com/como-hacer-un-login-en-java-con-base-de-datos-mysql/

Comment: Ese es el tuto, pero voy a buscar otro

Comment: Claro, ya he revisado el tutorial que nos comentas. Te iba a comentar que el código que has puesto no sigue estandares de nombrado y tiene revuelta la logica de la conexión a la BD con la de la pagina Web. Si sigues otro tutorial entendería que ya no daras seguimiento a esta pregunta ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: hola, segui otro tutorial, y me funciono perfectamente, muchas Gracias por la ayuda